# Notation for taking the derivative of $x \circ \delta$, where $(\mathcal{U},x)$ is a chart

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, notation, manifolds

I am currently studying differentiable manifolds and have been using this definition for a chart of a manifold $M$:

> Let $(M,\mathcal{O})$ be a manifold od dimension $d$. The the pair $(\mathcal{U},x)$ where $\mathcal{U}\in \mathcal{O}$ and $x:\mathcal{U} \to x(\mathcal{U}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, $p \mapsto x(p):=(x^{1}(p),...,x^{d}(p))$ is called a chart of the manifold. The component functions of $x$, $x^{i}: \mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,...d$, are then called the coordinates of the point $p\in M$ with respect to the chart $(\mathcal{U},x)$.

With this definition in mind, I have been working on reading through some lecture notes (from [here](https://youtu.be/UPGoXBfm6Js) at $34:23$) and noticed the following step (in $\color{red}{red}$) while proving that the tangent space $T_{p}M$ is closed under addition, i.e., $X_{\gamma,p} \oplus X_{\delta,p} \in T_{p}M$:

$$\begin{align*}
X_{\sigma,p}(f) &= (f \circ \sigma)'(0) \\
 &= [\underbrace{f \circ x^{-1}}_{\mathbb{R}^{d}\to \mathbb{R}}\circ \underbrace{((x\circ \gamma)+(x\circ \delta)-x(p))}_{\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{d}}]'(0) \label{a}\tag{1} \\
 &= [\partial_{a}(f\circ x^{-1})(x(p))] \color{red}{((x^{a}\circ\gamma)+(x^{a}\circ \delta) -x^{a}(p))'(0)} \label{b}\tag{2} \\
 &=(f\circ x^{-1}\circ x \circ \gamma)'(0)+(f\circ x^{-1}\circ x \circ \delta)'(0) \\ 
 &=X_{\gamma,p} \oplus X_{\delta,p}
\end{align*}$$

I left out some simplification of the work since it is not important to my question, which is the following: why does the author go from working with the chart-map $x$ in $(1)$ to working with the component functions, $\color{red}{x^a}$, of the chart-map in $(2)$? Is this just to emphasize that$$\begin{cases} 
      x^{1}: \mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{R} \\
      \vdots \\
       x^{d}: \mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{R} 
   \end{cases} \iff x: \mathcal{U} \to x(\mathcal{U})\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$$*i.e.,* giving the $x^{i}$'s is equivalent to giving the chart-map x? Please forgive me for avoiding the notation $x=(x^{1},...,x^{d})$ for the chart-map. I'm just trying to stick to how the lecturer writes these objects since i'm new to differential geometry.

Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Comment: He does it simply to write the chain rule, because most people are comfortable with the chain rule written in terms of partial derivatives. Of course, one could write the chain rule more abstractly as well: $(f\circ \sigma)'(0)= (f\circ x^{-1}\circ x\circ \sigma)'(0)=D(f\circ x^{-1})_{x(p)}\circ D(x\circ \sigma)_0[1]= D(f\circ x^{-1})_{x(p)}[(x\circ \sigma)'(0)]$. Here, the notation means that if $\mu:\Bbb{R}\to V$ is a curve in some Banach space $V$, then $\mu'(t):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mu(t+h)-\mu(t)}{h}$. On the other hand, I'm using the $D$ notation to mean the Frechet derivative.

Comment: Also, yes, providing $x$ is equivalent to providing $n$ component functions $x^1,\dots x^n$, because given $x$, we simply set $x^i:= \text{pr}^i\circ x$, where $\text{pr}^i:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ takes a tuple $(a^1,\dots, a^n)$ to $a^i$. Conversely, given $x^1,\dots, x^n$, we simply define $x(a):= (x^1(a),\dots, x^n(a))$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo : Gotcha! So is it correct to say $x$ is defined by its component functions $x^{i}$ and vice-versa?

Comment: yes that's right